# PHP DOMDocument ignoring XSD Schema

Tags: php, xml, xsd

Validating any VAST2.0 XML tag

```
$xsdPath='https://github.com/chrisdinn/vast/blob/master/lib/vast_2.0.1.xsd'
$domdoc= new DOMDocument(); 
$domdoc->loadHTML($xml_input); 
if(!$domdoc->schemaValidate($xsdPath)){/* ... */}
```

returns nonsense messages like `Error 1845: Element 'html': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.`

In my opinion, this does not really make sense because both the schema xsd and the vast xml do not contain or require a markup or element with the name .

Trying the same with

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->XML($xml_input);
$valid = $reader->setSchema($xsdPath);
$reader->read();
$reader->close();
```

returns the same error codes.

I checked the xsd twiche. It is the same like on https://github.com/chrisdinn/vast/blob/master/lib/vast_2.0.1.xsd.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you post contents of $xml_input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load XML you should use `loadXML()`, not `loadHTML()`:

```
$xsdPath = 'https://raw.github.com/chrisdinn/vast/master/lib/vast_2.0.1.xsd';
//                  ^^^
//                  using raw version
$domdoc= new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->loadXML($xml_input);
//           ^^^
//           Not loading HTML here
if (!$domdoc->schemaValidate($xsdPath)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I dereference the URI you give for the XSD schema document, I don't get an XSD schema document.  I get an HTML document which displays a rendering of the XSD schema document.  It makes perfect sense to me for a validator expecting to see an xs:schema element to issue the error message you quote, when instead it sees an HTML element.

You can either find a URI that actually serves the XML document your validator needs, or you can make a local copy and point to that local copy.  But expecting PHP's schema validation to find the XSD document buried in that HTML is asking more than you can reasonably expect.

Comment: It's generally true what you write, however, imagine the correct URI is used (e.g. `https://raw.github.com/chrisdinn/vast/master/lib/vast_2.0.1.xsd`) and the question remains the same, what would be your conclusion then? (If what you answer would be what actually happened, PHP would have told that it failed to load the XSD and not give concrete validation errors as outlined in the question)

Comment: @hakre, the XSD spec does require that XSD validators validate schema documents against the schema for schema documents.  If a validator is given a URI and asked to load a schema document, finds an HTML document there instead, and doesn't complain about the HTML element at the root of the 'schema document', then I'd be inclined to say that its error diagnostics could be better.  If the correct URI had been used and the same error message had arisen, then like Ian Wood I would have asked to see the XML input.

Answer (score 0):

The error is rather straight forward:

> Error 1845: Element 'html': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.

Means that the element `<html>` is not declared in the XSD therefore the document can not be validated with that XSD.

> In my opinion, this does not really make sense because both the schema xsd and the vast xml do not contain or require a markup or element with the name.

You're loading a HTML document. Regardless if the string/file contains that html element or not, the DOMDocument *does* contain it so the validation tries to validate it against the XSD and then fails because the XSD does not have any declaration for it.

Comment: If you use loadHTML, even XML becomes HTML :)

Comment: Yes, DOMDocument is in HTML mode then.